# Avoid mutiple tap in button when run thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a button, when user tap the button, i run a Thread to do Something.

When user tap many time to my button, i have many thread run in a same time.

How can i avoid it, when user multiple tap, i have run only thread run. When the first thread complete, the second thread can run.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a boolean that indicates you've acted on the click and started the thread. Something like this:

```
boolean threadStarted = false;

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (!threadStarted) {
        // start thread here
        threadStarted = true;
    } else {
        // Ignore this spurious click
    }
}
```

**Note: Don't forget to reset the boolean to false after the thread has completed**

Comment: maybe you should change **// start thread here** and **threadStarted = true;** places. But maybe nothing changes when you do that..

Comment: Actually makes no difference what order you do that in. The point is to ensure that on the second call to `onClick()` the boolean is set to `true`

Comment: @ZuzooVn most definitely NOT! This won't help your problem because you have no idea how long it will take to actually start the Thread. If you use mThread.isAlive() then it is likely that you will start the Thread multiple times. Just use the boolean as I suggested and make sure that you reset the boolean to false when the thread completes (or when you want to allow the user to start another one, whatever that condition is)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried: Add `myButton.setEnabled(false)` when button pressed and then add `myButton.setEnabled(true)` to the end of the thread.

Comment: This may work but usually doesn't. The problem is that the button clicks get queued in the message queue and if you click very quickly you can usually get more than 1 in there.

Comment: Then use AsyncTask **onPreExecute** you could disable and in **onPostExecute** you could enable it.

Comment: Just using AsyncTask isn't a solution to the problem. You still need a way to prevent multiple AsyncTasks from being run.

Answer (score 0):

Use asynctask for process. you can see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Using that if button is pressed once your ui will not able to touched untill the process is over.

Comment: Actually this isn't correct. The button clicks just generate events that go into the message queue. If you click fast enough you can get several events in the queue before the first `onClick()` is called. Using AsyncTask won't prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in xamarin android. Fixed it in diffrent way. Same Idea also applicable for android Java developers.

```
public  class SingleClickListener
{
    public SingleClickListener(Action<object, EventArgs> setOnClick)
    {
        _setOnClick = setOnClick;
    }
    private bool hasClicked;

    private Action<object, EventArgs> _setOnClick;

    public void OnClick(object v, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!hasClicked)
        {
            _setOnClick(v, e);
            hasClicked = true;
        }
        reset();
    }

    private void reset()
    {
        Android.OS.Handler mHandler = new Android.OS.Handler();
        mHandler.PostDelayed(new Action(() => { hasClicked = false; }), 500);
    }
}
```